# How can i add shortcut to powershell for a terminal server user?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-services

I have a user that need access to powershell on his terminal server account, how can i do this?

Comment: For just one user or for all users that use the TS? If its one user can you not go in to the local profile and simply place a shortcut on the desktop?

Comment: @CharlesH thx for reply,, I would like to know how to do it for all users.

Comment: Administration tool users on the server? It is better to equip them with flamethrowers)

Comment: small server with only admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Powershell is a bit different because its got separate permissions.

However to simply get the Shortcut available to all users you can use the Public User folder. If its Server 2008/2012 on the root drive you'll have C:\users... in here you will have Default and Public (will be hidden).

Default is what the new users that log on profiles are based on so if you put the shortcut in here on the desktop all new users will have that created on their desktop.

Public is a shared user so all new and current users see their own desktop as well as the public desktop so if you place the shortcut in public desktop it should appear for all users instantly.

Hope that helps!